# Redirecting the UDP packets but not able to print the data

Tags: sockets, redirect, udp, openvswitch

I have this setup of systems where 3 VMs are connected to OVS.

On one system I am running UDP server on VM1 and VM3 and UDP client VM2.

In VM2, the packets from UDP client are destined to VM1 (destination address and port as mentioned in the code). But at the OVS, I have provided the rule where if the source IP is VM2 and destination is VM1, I am redirecting the UDP packets to VM3.

I am able to see the counter matching the rule and even I have observed the change of destination and port at the interface of the new destination in the wireshark.

But the problem is the I am not able to read the packets in the UDP server program in VM3

Can any one help please

EDIT : The below is the screen shot when trying to redirect packets from a TCP connection. I am not able to send the packet to the destination

[image]

Comment: How did you redirect packets to VM3 in Open vSwitch? Did you change the IP and Ethernet addresses?

Comment: I have changed only the IP address. The below is the rule I have used
`ovs-ofctl add-flow sw1 udp,nw_src=192.168.10.20,nw_dst=192.168.10.22,tp_dst=20001,idle_timeout=0,priority=40000,actions=mod_nw_dst=192.168.10.21,normal`

Comment: Earlier I have used `output:<port_no>` in actions

Comment: Thanks for the Hint. I have got it when I have included the MAC address

Comment: Glad to know I could help. I've made this into a short answer to help anyone else who might forget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the virtual machine's networking stack to accept those redirected packets, you will have to **rewrite the destination IP and Ethernet addresses** as well.

Comment: Is this the same process for TCP redirection ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for TCP.

Comment: `ovs-ofctl add-flow ovs_bridge tcp,nw_src=192.168.1.108,nw_dst=192.168.1.106,tp_dst=8001,idle_timeout=0,actions=mod_nw_dst=192.168.1.107,mod_dl_dst=08:00:27:d2:b6:be,normal`
Its establishing the connection with 106 and trying to send the packets to 107. 107 is resetting the connection